# Swagger Dynamic Value Types

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to figure out how to model a schema that contains a list of dynamic value type in swagger and I was wondering if it is even possible. Take a json structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2fffae57-55f2-4fef-ad53-cf3d303611cf",
        "type": "cookie",
        "data": {
            "flavor": "chocolate chip"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "7ef944a6-3243-4dfc-82ef-691939f684bd",
        "type": "electronics",
        "data": {
            "device": "radio"
        }
    }
]
```

In this case I am returning a list of objects but one field in the object can have several different types depending upon the context of the data. The outer structure and both varieties of inner structure have dozens of fields. I want to know if there is a way to model this in swagger?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use [Dictionaries, HashMaps and Associative Arrays](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/)